# Objective c: setting an object attribute ; attribute not updating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Wow. I have had a total mental failure this morning stuck on this 101 problem.

In `ViewController`, I have this code. But after it executes, the value of `[proposalInfo expanded]` is still NO. Can somebody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)showFullProposal:(id) sender {

// update proposalinfo
ProposalInfo *proposalInfo = [self.proposalInfoArray objectAtIndex:index.section];
[proposalInfo setExpanded:YES];

}
```

The variables are declared as follows:

ViewController:

```
@interface ViewController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* proposalInfoArray;

@end
```

ProposalInfo.h:

```
@interface ProposalInfo : NSObject

@property (assign) BOOL expanded;

@end
```

ProposalInfo.m:

```
@synthesize expanded;
```

Please help!!

Comment: what about your `setExpanded:` method in proposalinfo????

Comment: @I'MPOSSIBLE The `setExpanded:` method is synthesized.

Comment: @I'MPOSSIBLE there's no need for an explicit setExpanded method since the property has been synthesized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you never `alloc`/`init` your `proposalInfoArray` array, you could experience behavior like this (i.e. get no error, but always get `NO` back because when you send a message to a `nil` object, you get `nil` back). If not precisely this, it's going to be something simple like that. Check `proposalInfoArray` and make sure it's not `nil`. Also check the `proposalInfo` object you got back, make sure it's not `nil`.

To illustrate your likely problem, this reproduces the behavior you describe (e.g. `expanded` looks like it's `NO`, regardless, but you still don't get any exception):

```
self.proposalInfoArray = nil;                   // This obviously won't work

[self.proposalInfoArray addObject:[[ProposalInfo alloc] init]];

ProposalInfo *proposalInfo = [self.proposalInfoArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"before=%d", proposalInfo.expanded);      // OK, IT'S "0"
proposalInfo.expanded = YES;
NSLog(@"after=%d", proposalInfo.expanded);       // HEY, IT'S STILL "0" -- BAD!
```

Whereas this works properly:

```
self.proposalInfoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.proposalInfoArray addObject:[[ProposalInfo alloc] init]];

ProposalInfo * proposalInfo = [self.proposalInfoArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"before=%d", proposalInfo.expanded);      // OK, IT'S "0"
proposalInfo.expanded = YES;
NSLog(@"after=%d", proposalInfo.expanded);       // HEY, IT'S NOW "1" -- GOOD!
```

In terms of how to identify these issues in the future, use `NSAssert`. We would have found this problem if we had the following line of code before the `objectAtIndex` line:

```
NSAssert(self.proposalInfoArray, @"proposalInfoArray must be initialized!");
```

or, after the `objectForIndex`:

```
NSAssert(proposalInfo, @"proposalInfo must not be nil!");
```

The nice thing about `NSAssert` statements is that you can put them in your code, and when you build for debugging, they help you find your program logic mistakes, but when you build your final release version, they're automatically omitted, making your code more efficient. So, use `NSAssert` liberally!

Comment: Thanks.. I'll check that and post back here.

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you. It was indeed the problem of not initializing the array first. I would expect it to throw an error message or something. Anyway it's fixed now, that's the main thing!

Answer (score 2):

Imme, the following line seems to be strange:

```
ProposalInfo *proposalInfo = [self.proposalInfoArray objectAtIndex:index.section];
```

Actually, what do you have in your array, means in `proposalInfoArray`.
Have you checked your object?

Comment: I suspect you're right about `proposalInfoArray`, but I'm not sure what you find odd about that line of code. I'm assuming Imme has a tableview with one section per proposal, and is probably trying to keep track of whether that section is expanded or not.

Comment: Rob, actually the point which strange me is that Imme is trying to assining his "proposalInfo" object with this, the point is that the array whether has such object and if it is then it's retain or not. More, possibly as per my thinking this object is creating that problem; once imme shout over me about this object then only I can think other aspect as just few sec back I tried to use this in my sample code and it's providing what Imme wants.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with this construct. It's a very common pattern, to set some local pointer variable to point to an object in an array. Sure, during the scope of that loop, the object has an additional strong reference, but it's resolved as soon as the `proposalInfo` pointer falls out of scope or is set to something else. The only thing that's a tad bit dangerous is the lack of `isKindOf` logic (but if he got an object of the wrong type, an exception would have been raised, so that's not the issue), but this overall pattern is not at all unusual.

Comment: Thank you for the input on this aspect.